# Clojure: iterate over map of sets

Tags: clojure, lisp, idioms

This is pretty much a follow-up to my last question ([Clojure idiomatic way to update multiple values of map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686631/clojure-idiomatic-way-to-update-multiple-values-of-map)), but not quite the same. (keep in mind that I'm fairly new to Clojure and functional languages alike)

suppose I have the following data structure, defined as a map of sets:

```
(def m1 {:1 #{2} :2 #{1 3} :3 #{1}})
```

and a map of maps as such:

```
(def m2 {:1 {:1 0 :2 12 :3 23} :2 {:1 23 :2 0 :3 4} :3 {:1 2 :2 4 :3 0}})
```

What I want to do is update the registries of `m2` that have a correspondence in m1 to a certain value. Let's say the value I want is `x`. The resulting `m2` would be something like this:

```
{:1 {:1 0 :2 x :3 23} :2 {:1 x :2 0 :3 x} :3 {:1 x :2 4 :3 0}}
```

Assuming that `v` contains every possible key for my map, y first attempt, (that I failed miserably) is to do something like this: (assume that `x=1`

```
(for [i v]
 reduce (fn [m j] (assoc-in m [i j] 1)) d (i m1)))
```

needless to say that it was a failure. So, how is the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your requirements you want to

1. Produce a number of key-sequences from `m1`.
2. In `m2` associate each of those key-sequences with a particular constant value.

The first step is a fairly simple transformation of `m1`. We want to produce *0 or more key-seqs* for each entry (depending on how many are in its set), so the natural go-to for me is `mapcat`. It stands for `map`-then-`concat` and is great for just such a case where from each element of a seq we produce 0 or more of the elements we want.

```
(defn key-seqs [coll]
  (mapcat 
   (fn [[k v]] 
     (map (partial vector k) v))
   coll))

(key-seqs m1)
;;=> ([:1 2] [:2 1] [:2 3] [:3 1])
```

Note that the function taken by `mapcat` is itself a `map`, so that it produces a *sequence* (possibly empty) for `mapcat` to unroll. But this is returning the longs stored in the sets as themselves. If we want to turn them into keywords to match `m2` we need a little more processing:

```
(defn key-seqs [coll]
  (mapcat 
   (fn [[k v]] 
     (map (comp (partial vector k) keyword str) v))
   coll))

(key-seqs m1)
;;=> ([:1 :2] [:2 :1] [:2 :3] [:3 :1])
```

(We need to use `str` because `keyword` doesn't know what to do with longs. Normally keywords are not numbers, but names with some symbolic meaning)

Then we can adapt the `update-m` from your previous question a little bit so that it can take the constant value as an argument and handle key-sequences that don't just have the same value twice:

```
(defn update-m [m x v]
  (reduce (fn [m' key-seq]
            (assoc-in m' key-seq x)) ;; accumulate changes
          m   ;; initial-value
          v)) ;; collection to loop over
```

and now we seem to be in business:

```
(update-m m2 1 (key-seqs m1))
;;=> {:1 {:1 0, :2 1, :3 23}, :2 {:1 1, :2 0, :3 1}, :3 {:1 1, :2 4, :3 0}}
```

Comment: Much easier if OP just uses numbers as keys to begin with, instead of these pseudo-number keywords in the question.

Comment: You sir/lady, is amazing. 
Just one question: Could you explain a little further how this line works:

`(map (comp (partial vector k) keyword str) v))`

I mean, what exactly is `comp` doing here? I get that it's composing the partial function and transforming str into a keyword But can you explain a little bit further?

Comment: @amalloy If I did, how easier it would be? I mean, is there a straightforward solution for this case?

Comment: The basic process is that `mapcat` iterates over entries `[k v]`, starting with `[:1 #{2}]`. With `comp` and `partial` it produces a function like `(fn [num] (vector :1 (keyword (str num))))`, which it maps over all the *numbers in the set* `v`. That gives a sequence of vectors where all the first members are `:1`, which is handed back to `mapcat`. That then combines all these sequences into one sequence. 
It can take a little while to learn to read these `comp`&`partial` combinations, as in the returned function the data flows first from the last argument fn and towards the left.

Answer (score 2):

I think a nice solution would be, if you change the data structure of m1 to something like

```
(def m1-new [[:1 :2] [:2 :1] [:2 :3] [:3 :1]])
```

Then you can just `reduce` over it and use `assoc-in`.

```
(reduce (fn [m path] (assoc-in m path my-new-value)) m2 m1-new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (here x is 100)

```
(merge-with merge m2 
   (into {} (for [[k v] m1] [k (into {} (for [i v] [(keyword (str i)) 100]))])))
```

**EDIT:**

The idea is this:

- Convert m1 from `{:1 #{2} :2 #{1 3} :3 #{1}}` to `{:1 {:2 x} :2 {:1 x :3 x} :3 {:1 x}}` which is basically converting each set to a map where key is the values of the set and values are the constant x.
- Merge both the m2 and new m1.

NOTE: There is an assumption that all the keys in m1 are there in m2.